# Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference with more number of lines

Tags: fortran

I get this problem since there are more number of lines (ndt=112256), whereas, when the number of lines are less (say, if ndt=69888), it works fine.

I tried increasing the maximum limit in the first few lines of the code

```
    real dt,crad,p
    dimension dt(9000000),crad(9000000),p(1000)
    dimension a(90000000)
    integer rvac

    ndt=112256

    open (unit=1,file='x.dat')
    open (unit=4,file='x1.dat')
    do j=1,1000
    p(j)=0.0d0
    enddo
    do i=1,ndt
    read(1,*) dt(i), a(i), crad(i)
    rvac = crad(i)
    if (rvac.le.180)then
    p(rvac)=p(rvac)+1
    endif
    enddo
    sum=0.
    sum1=0.
    do rvac=1,180
    write(4,*) rvac,p(rvac),p(rvac)/ndt
c111    format(f12.5,3x,f12.5)
    enddo
c

    stop
    end
```

I get error as:

"Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

#0  0x2B76431D4777

#1  0x2B76431D4D7E

#2  0x2B764350BCAF

#3  0x400BA8 in MAIN__ at prob.f:?

Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't used Fortran in .gt.40 years but is it possible that crad(i) can be -ve sometimes?

Comment: Compile with debug options on so you will know at which line the program crashes. Use `IMPLICITE NONE` so all variables have to be declared. Use option for boundary checking. Does the file `x.dat` contain enough data?  Better no to use the low unit number, better would be to use unit number > 10. Problem looks like not directly related to Fortran 95, so better to use tag fortran.

Comment: crad(i) is positive.

Comment: @albert, the file `x.dat` has a huge number of data/lines (ie.,`112256=ndt`), as i have mentioned in my question.Is this huge data/number of lines making the error..??

Comment: I don't think the huge number is making the problem. See my other remarks how to tackle the problem. Also check the result of the read statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921730/where-is-the-cause-of-this-segmentation-fault-where-1-is-entered-into-the-item might be helpful

Comment: The backtrace suggests that you're using some version of gfortran.  Try adding `-Wall -fcheck=all` to your command line.  This may help find the issue.  You can also change your read statement to `read(1,*,err=10,end=20)` and add labeled error messages after your `stop`.  For example, `10 stop "Read error"`